# twisted python - tac, or py?

Tags: python, twisted, convention

I'm hoping this is going to be the simplest question I ever ask here! I've googled etc, but not found anything definitive. I have a .tac file - which I know is a twisted application. I can run this by executing:

```
twistd -ny mailserver.tac
```

if I did the following, would the behaviour be any different (ie, what IS so significant about using the twistd executable, and .tac suffix files?

```
mv mailserver.tac mailserver.py
python mailserver.py
```

or even, without the rename:

```
python mailserver.tac
```

Any guidance on the differences would be welcomed!

Comment: dupliacte - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897939/how-do-you-you-run-a-twisted-application-via-python-instead-of-via-twisted

Comment: What is in `mailserver.py`?

Comment: Basically I was trying to work on mailserver.tac (http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/emailserver.tac) in a windows env, using eclipse and pyDev - but that (unsurprisingly) doesnt recognise tac files. All good though thanks to @WeaselFox pointing out the one thing I'd failed to find by googling ;) If anyone thinks there is value in me pasting my "new" mailserver.py code as an answer by way of a demonstration of how a script can be python / twistd friendly, happy to do so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file extension doesn't really matter.  All `twistd` (and even `python`) does is read the contents and evaluate them.  The filename is almost entirely irrelevant.

However, using `twistd` instead of `python` to run the file is pretty important.  If you run a file that is *meant* to be a `.tac` file using `python` that little or nothing of interest will happen.  This should be evident from reading the `.tac` file.  None of the important code that makes anything interesting happen gets executed according to the normal rules of how `python` evaluates and executes a source file.

Consider `emailserver.tac`.  The only top-level code it includes is a few class definitions and a call to a function that instantiates and returns an `Application` instance.  If you evaluate this with `python` you'll get an `Application` instance and then the program will complete and exit.  Compare this to what happens if you use `twistd` - which the same things as `python` does but then **also** starts the application and runs the reactor.